# Invalid Monitor Handle Error When Executing SetMonitorBrightness Function In Windows - C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am writing a program in Windows and I want to get the brightness of a computer monitor. I am using the Windows GetMonitorBrightness function, however I am having some trouble.

this is my code so far:

```
DWORD dw;
HMONITOR hMonitor = NULL;
DWORD cPhysicalMonitors;
LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR pPhysicalMonitors = NULL;

LPDWORD pdwMinimumBrightness=NULL;
LPDWORD pdwCurrentBrightness=NULL;
LPDWORD pdwMaximumBrightness=NULL;

HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, NULL);

hMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL);

BOOL bSuccess = GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, &cPhysicalMonitors);
pPhysicalMonitors = (LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR)malloc(cPhysicalMonitors* sizeof(PHYSICAL_MONITOR));
bSuccess = GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, cPhysicalMonitors, pPhysicalMonitors);
bSuccess = GetMonitorBrightness(hMonitor, pdwMinimumBrightness, pdwCurrentBrightness, pdwMaximumBrightness);
```

I wrote this following the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

but when I run this code I get an error saying "This function failed because an invalid monitor handle was passed to it".

I can't see anything wrong with the code I wrote, but I cannot seem to figure out the reason for this error.

**EDIT:** I should mention I am trying this out on a CRT monitor

**EDIT 2:** Fixed this problem, turns out I wasn't passing a proper handle to GetMonitorBrightness.

```
bSuccess = GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, cPhysicalMonitors, pPhysicalMonitors);
HANDLE pmh = pPhysicalMonitors[0].hPhysicalMonitor; //<---------------  
bSuccess = GetMonitorBrightness(pmh, pdwMinimumBrightness, pdwCurrentBrightness, pdwMaximumBrightness);
```

Adding the marked line above, solved this problem

Comment: Did you do error checking anywhere else, like where you retrieved the handle to use?

Comment: You're also passing in unallocated memory for `GetMonitorBrightness` to fill in for the last three arguments. The most proper way is to make a `DWORD` and pass in the address.

Answer (score 1):

Add `#pragma comment(lib,"Dxva2.lib")` next to the `#include file`.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking the return value of `MonitorFromWindow`. If the monitor is not found, it will return `NULL` because you have passed `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL`. Null is not a monitor handle.

Try `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST` or `MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried both ways but I still get the same result.

Comment: @user206631, and have you checked the return values? You don't seem to be checking the value of `hMonitor` or `bSuccess` at any point. You should check them and if they are zero or NULL call `GetLastError` to find out what went wrong.